# Can a Windows DirectAccess Server also be a RRAS server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, rras, direct-access

We are upgrading our domain to Windows server 2008 R2 and I was wondering if anyone here has ever tried to make a directaccess server run RRAS so that you could also support standard VPN clients as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DirectAccess server, must have two public static IPv4 addresses.
Than it uses HTTPS protocol to establish connection.
Also, after VPN is up-and-running, it uses only IPv6 for VPN, so you might need some of 6-to-4 technologies.

Yes, it is possible to have standard VPN PPTP or IPsec on same RRAS server where is DirectAcces, because it uses different ports/protocols in parallel :)